# How to flush the queue in DragonFly Mail Agent (DMA)

Tags: email, mail-queue, dragonfly-bsd, dragonfly-mail-agent

DMA keeps on trying to send this EMail:

```
$ dma -bp
ID  : c08be.177cb00
From: example@foo.bar
To  : example@foo.bar
```

How can I flush the queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful for someone:

Retrieve the PID and kill the process

```
$ ps -ef | grep dma
mail      6922     1 66 Jun28 ?        15:31:04 /usr/sbin/dma -q1
$ kill -9 6922
```

Answer (score 2):

If the files are no longer required you can **delete** those with this command:

```
rm /var/spool/dma/*.*
```